# The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.sql

Tags: sql, datediff

```
select 
    DateDiff(Day, convert(datetime,'2/1/'+cast(Year(BeginDate) as varchar)), 
    convert(datetime,'2/29/'+cast(Year(BeginDate) as varchar))) 
from [table] 
where (begindate is not null and enddate is not null)
```

I am running into the error

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range datetime value.

Example of Begindate:  2014-02-12 00:00:00.000
example of enddate: 2014-02-16 00:00:00.000

Please help point me toward in the right directions, thanks.

Comment: Well, if an example of `BeginDate` is `2014-02-12`, then how do you expect `'2/29/2014'` to be converted to a datetime?. 2014 is **not** a leap year

Comment: well I b darned, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score -1):

This error is due to the way different languages represent and parse dates in the SQL Server. If English is set as your default language, the SQL Server expects dates in MM/DD/YYYYformat. Other languages may expect a DD/MM/YYYY format. The SQL Server will throw this error in the event of a mismatch between what is provided and what the SQL Server is expecting.

Comment: Plz. consider to post an example in your answer